# Respuesta Entity HttpClient

Tags: java, http-post

Solicito de su colaboracion debdio a que me encuentro consumiendo información de una web y no se cual es el problema que me esta generando, debido a que en alguna peticiones puedo hacer `String mensaje = EntityUtils.toString(entity);` y me funciona, pero acabo de hacer la implementacion para otro metodo y ya no lo puedo hacer me sale lo siguiente: `java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.`; la implementación en la siguiente:

```
public void buscarRadicado(HttpClient httpclient, HttpPost httpost) throws Exception
    {
        List <NameValuePair> nameValuePair = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpEntity entity = null;

        try 
        {
            {
                for(int index = 0; index < 10 ; ++index )
                {
                    httpost = new HttpPost("path");
                    // Parametros de la consulta
                    nameValuePair = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "CONSULTAR"));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cod_tipo", "25"));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_int", 123456));
                    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uno", ""));

                    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, Consts.UTF_8));
                    response = response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                    entity = response.getEntity();
                    mensaje = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                    entity = null;
                    httpost = null;
                    response = null;
                    guardarMensaje(mensaje);
                    mensaje = "se guardo Correctamente";
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            httpost.releaseConnection();
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            httpost.releaseConnection();
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Código de respuesta: `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` **200**

Content-Type: `response.getEntity().getContentType();` **text/html**

Answer (score 0):

entity = response.getEntity(); regresa un valor null ya que no tiene informacion en la clase.Si quieres tener un valor necesitas response.setEntity()